# Dummy Variables for Data Frame Containing only Predictors

Tags: r

I know how to create a matrix with dummy variables if the response variable is part of the initial matrix:

`trainx  = model.matrix(survived ~ . -1, data = train)`

However, how can I do it for a matrix that only contains the predictors?  It's the test set so there are no predictors.  I don't know how the syntax works for that situation.

```
model.matrix(~test)
Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'test'
```

Have tried various combinations and nothing works.  Note `test` contains columns that are factors as well as numeric.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`model.matrix(~., data=test)`

In other words, omit the LHS of the formula. Don't put the dataset name into the formula itself!